# Cycles Combined bake black spots

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image]I have created my textures in Substance Painter and applied them via nodes in cycles node editor.

However when I try to do a combined bake I get black spots on places where the normal map information are.

The normal map is created from high poly to low poly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my high poly mesh being in the same scene. Even though it was hidden it botched the baking. After moving the high poly  to a different scene the problem disappeared.

Comment: Even if you've solved your problem, I would leave the question so others can find it when they run into the same problem.